Keep GUI alive when Disconnecting RDP Connection to Windows Server
I want to close a RDP connection to my Windows Server with programs running, but when i do so, it closes the GUI and some programs break.
I need the GUI to remain completely active, similar to leaving a PC unlocked or just turning off the Monitor.
I tried using this batch script i found:
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do ( %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console )
This only places a "Please Wait" Screen until i reconnect via RDP. Not how i want it to work.
